# Retrieve table data from an image

Tags: python, image

I am downloading an image of a table shown below and I want to extract the table data. I have tried AWS Textract to achieve this goal but for some reason it is not able to differentiate between some values and also appends extra values. It would take a long time to come up with a way to deal with this. Is there any other way to extract the data from this table?

[Image I am trying to extract data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDoPm.jpg)

Comment: it is not easy problem. Even Google Tesseract-OCR or other OCR tool may have problem if you don't preprocess image first. But even this may not be enough. [Tesseract - Improve Quality of output](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)

Comment: Is the data available in other formats? Some API, XML, ...?

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and almost certainly off-topic.